# Google Calendar Invite a standard group

Tags: google-calendar

I am running a podcast and every week we do a show, however It is not always on the same day and there are new guests each week, so I don't want to make it a regular meeting.

That being said what I really want to be able to do is say "Invite the normal group" and have it invite everyone in that group so I don't forget anyone

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're just using the normal Google tools, this is baked in.

First, you'll want to add the contacts for your "normal group" into a Contact Group in [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com). Give it a unique name that's easy to find. ("Podcast Invitees" seems like a reasonable name.)

Then, when you make your event, just go to the full edit screen. Start entering the name of your group in the "Add guests" field. You'll eventually get to a short list of possible attendees, including your group. Simply click (or use the arrow keys to select then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to add all of the members of that group to the event as guests.

[image: "Add guests" screen shot]

Once entered, the list will expand to all of the members of the group. Then just save the event as normal.

Note that if you add someone new to the contact group (or remove someone) they'll not be added to (or removed from) events that have already been created, but the new list will be up to date for your next event. Note also that I believe that there's a limit to the number of people you can invite to an event. Also, not everyone will be keen to see their name among a list of many others; they may not want their contact information exposed.

Alternatively, you can create a [Google Group](https://groups.google.com) and add people to it (or invite people to add themselves) and you can invite the email address for the Group to invite the members to your event.

Answer (score -2):

In standard Google Calendar, normal groups are not displayed in the "Add guests" field because they do not have an e-mail address.

You would need a mailing list, such as a Google Group.

Comment: This is demonstrably not true, as shown in my answer. You need to use the full web interface, however. On mobile web and in the Android app it does not appear possible.